# Catching "all other" characters in ANTLR

Tags: antlr, grammar, character, lexer

I am trying to integrate an ANTLR-defined grammar into NetBeans, and so far valid syntax is working fine.  However, currently if you enter any character that's not defined in the language somewhere (for example, the '?' character) the custom editor immediately crashes because it fails to find a rule for that character.

Is there a way in ANTLR to catch and skip EVERY character that doesn't match a rule (and perhaps output an error message) without having the whole lexer crash and burn?  I would like to just flag invalid characters, skip over them, and continue lexing, something like:

```
//some rules + tokens

invalidCharacter
    :    <<catch all other characters>>
        {System.out.println("undefined character entered!")}
    ;
```

Any help would be apprciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're only interested in illegal chars inside the lexer, something as simple as this might do the trick for you:

```java
grammar T;

@lexer::members {
  public List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
}

parse
  :  .* EOF
  ;

INT
  :  '0'..'9'+
  ;

WORD
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
  ;

SPACE
  :  ' ' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
  ;

INVALID
  :  . {
         errors.add("Invalid character: '" + $text + "' on line: " +
             getLine() + ", index: " + getCharPositionInLine());
       }
  ;
```

As you can see, only integers and ascii words are accepted, all other chars will cause an error to be added to the `List` inside the lexer. When parsing a string like `"abc 123 ? foo !"` with the test class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("abc 123 ? foo !"));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    tokens.toString(); // dummy call to toString() which causes all tokens to be created
    if(!lexer.errors.isEmpty()) {
      for(String error : lexer.errors) {
        System.out.println(error);
      }
    }
    else {
      TParser parser = new TParser(tokens);
      parser.parse();
    }
  }
}
```

will cause the following output:

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool T.g
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main

Invalid character: '?' on line: 1, index: 9
Invalid character: '!' on line: 1, index: 15
```

Comment: That seems to work fine for isolated characters but if you have a lot of them strung together it fails...for example input "!!!!????~~~~"

Comment: @donnyton, well, for `n` invalid characters, it creates `n` different messages. If that is not what you want, you'll need to explain yourself a bit more.

Comment: When I try integrating the new grammar into NetBeans, it detects single invalid keystrokes properly but crashes when I copy paste many invalid characters, or open a file with many invalid characters.  However, I have figured out a solution--define INVALID as a fragment and make an "invalidSequence" rule that handles them in more depth.